# uhmm im kinda new to node.js well im new to scripting in general but i hope someone can help me. I am reiciving this in the terminal

Tags: node.js

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '~';
const fs= require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
```

**This is where the problem seems to be**
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);**This line of code in particular is where it keps pointing me to**

```
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Codelyon is online!');
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }else if(command == 'youtube'){
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
    }else if(command == 'mmm'){
        client.commands.get('addrolemod').execute(message, args);
    }else if(command == 'rmm'){
        client.commands.get('removerolemod').execute(message, args);
    }else if(command == 'message'){
        client.commands.get('message').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }else{
        message.channel.send('Are you stupid?');
    }
});
```

Error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)        
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GameMaker\Documents\DiscordBot1\main.js:10:21)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

Comment: Please include the error also.

Comment: There is the error

Comment: Seems fine to me. Are you sure that's where it is pointing. Please include that in the error part too.

Comment: i know it seems fine to me too but then it suddenly stopped working

Comment: are you sure you dont see anything wrong with it?

Comment: There is probably a syntax error in one of the JavaScript file in the commands folder. You can try to remove all the files before putting them back one by one, until you find the one throwing the Unexpected identifier error.